# How to find out the calling component in the getter method?

Tags: java, jsf

In my page, I have 2 (and later many more) image containers.  I want to bind their url property, so that each container would have different source, according to its id.
I have something like this in my JSP:

```html
<webuijsf:image id="image2" binding="#{Page1.img_2}" url="#{Page1.imgSRC}" />
```

In the backing bean code I have an `imgSRC` getter, however I want to be able to know in the getter from which component it was been called and based on the component's ID I'll use some sort of `switch` to decide which URL to return to the component.

Is this possible at all? If so, how?

Comment: That's not exactly JSP+Servlet. That's JSF. I've edited the title and tags accordingly.

Comment: Can't you use polymorphism instead of differentiating by object type?

Answer (score 8):

As you're using the Woodstock component library which was abandoned over 4 years ago, I'll bet that you're maintaining a legacy JSF 1.x application which was never upgraded to replace the dead Woodstock component library. There is in JSF 1.x no API-provided method which allows you to obtain the current component in the getter.

In JSF 2.x you could have used [`UIComponent#getCurrentComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCurrentComponent%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) for this:

```
public String getImgSRC() {
    UIComponent component = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    // ...
}
```

But in JSF 1.x this method is not available. I'd suggest a different approach. If the sole purpose is to eliminate the property/getter boilerplate code, then you could use a `Map` instead to hold the values. Maps can be treated like Javabeans in EL.

Something like this:

```
private static Map<String, String> imageURLs = new HashMap<String, String>();

static {
    imageURLs.put("img1", "foo.png");
    imageURLs.put("img2", "bar.png");
    imageURLs.put("img3", "baz.png");
    // ...
}

public Map<String, String> getImageURLs() {
    return imageURLs;
}
```

Which can be used as:

```html
<webuijsf:image url="#{Page1.imageURLs.img1}" />
<webuijsf:image url="#{Page1.imageURLs.img2}" />
<webuijsf:image url="#{Page1.imageURLs.img3}" />
...
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.  as my question implied, i'm taking a java course, so i'm using the Woodstock component library as part of the NetBeans 6.5 IDE which was supplied in my course's book (Deitel's Java).  i'll try to use JSF 2.x, as your second solution left me in the same position as i'm currently in - each image container would have to use a different binding, while i want to use the same for all images, and the getter should return a response according to the component which is using it.

Comment: Wow, that book must be really outdated. For quick moving subjects such as programming languages and all ICT-related stuff, you should really be looking for books which are published no more than 1 year ago. Note that using the `binding` attribute this way is a very poor practice. To get started with JSF and to find links to more recent/decent tutorials, I suggest to get through our JSF wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info They are listed at the bottom. There's by the way also a wiki page on Woodstock, for the case you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/woodstock/info