# Primefaces autocomplete keep selected dropdown value

Tags: javascript, java, drop-down-menu, primefaces, autocomplete

I have a **Primefaces autocomplete box**, and have the requirement to **keep the value of the dropdown list on the selected value**, for example I have a list with 20 elements and I select the 10 element.

[image]

If I want to select another value when I select the dropdown **It starts on the beginning of the list**:

[image]

This is my primefaces code:

```
<p:autoComplete id="transportLAvailable" dropdown="true"
    value="#{remissionOrderReportController.selectedTLineFilter}"
    forceSelection="true" requiredMessage="Some message"
    completeMethod="#{remissionOrderReportController.searchFromTLinesList}"
    var="transportFiltered" itemLabel="#{transportFiltered.name}"
    itemValue="#{transportFiltered}" converter="#{transportLineConverter}">
        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="@this"
        listener="#{remissionOrderReportController.findVehicleByTL(transportFiltered)}"/>
</p:autoComplete>
```

I don't have problems saving the values, just with the view.

¿Is there a way to do this on an attribute of **p:autoComplete or javascript**?

Comment: What is your PF version?

Comment: @Kukeltje 6.1.0

Comment: Create a  [mcve] and try with 6.2 or 7.0 please. IIRC, a fix was created in an in a later release. Check the issue list and releasenotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to simply include the current value at the top of the returned list. I do it like this:

```
public List<T> autoCompleteItems(final String query) {
  List<T> results = ...; // Find results for the query
  addBoundValue(Components.getCurrentComponent(), results);
  return results;
}

protected void addBoundValue(UIInput input, List<T> results) {
  if (input.getValue() != null && typeTclass.isAssignableFrom(input.getValue().getClass())) {
    T bound = typeTclass.cast(input.getValue());
    results.remove(bound); // If it's already in the list, remove it first
    results.add(0, bound); // Add the value at the top of the list
  }
}
```

This code comes from a generic bean which uses the type of the list as a parameter (type is set in the constructor to `typeTclass`).

Please note that I'm using [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/) to get the [current component](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/3.3/org/omnifaces/util/Components.html#getCurrentComponent--). It will get you the the `p:autoComplete` component, from which you can read the value.

If you can't use OmniFaces, please read [How to find out the calling component in the getter method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126091/how-to-find-out-the-calling-component-in-the-getter-method)